# simple "if"-less algebraic computation using CLOS

Tags: object-oriented, lisp

For educational purposes I've tried to implement a simple algebraic OOP example using CLOS. The functionality is as far as I can say as it is supposed to be. The intended approach was to implement a simple example of ideomatic OOP polymorphism. For a greater learning experience I've wanted to show the code to get suggestions, critic and so on.

```
;; main node class, most general
(defclass node ()
  ;; abstract class for nodes
  ((value :initarg :value :reader value)))

(defgeneric evaluate (node)
  (:documentation "the standard evaluation"))


;; node containing an operation, more specific
(defclass op-node (node)
  ;; abstract class for a node containing an operation
  ((left-node  :initform nil :initarg :left-node  :reader left-node)
   (right-node :initform nil :initarg :right-node :reader right-node)))

(defmethod evaluate ((node op-node))
  (apply (value node) 
         (list (evaluate (left-node node))
               (evaluate (right-node node)))))


;; concrete nodes
(defclass add-node (op-node)
  ;; class for addition
  ((value :initform #'+ :reader value)))

(defclass minus-node (op-node)
  ;; class for subtraction
  ((value :initform #'- :reader value)))

(defclass multi-node (op-node)
  ;; class for multiplication
  ((value :initform #'* :reader value)))


(defclass value-node (node)
  ;; class for a node containing a numerical value
  ((value :initarg :value :reader value)))

(defmethod evaluate (value-node)
  (value value-node))


;; 1 + 3
(setf *simple-add* (make-instance 'add-node 
                                  :left-node  (make-instance 'value-node :value 1)
                                  :right-node (make-instance 'value-node :value 3)))

;; 1 * 10
(setf *simple-multi* (make-instance 'multi-node
                                    :left-node  (make-instance 'value-node :value 1)
                                    :right-node (make-instance 'value-node :value 10)))

;; (1 + 3) + (1 * 10)
(setf *advanced-add* (make-instance 'add-node
                                    :left-node *simple-add*
                                    :right-node *simple-multi*))

(evaluate *simple-add*)   ;; => 4
(evaluate *simple-multi*  ;; => 10
(evaluate *advanced-add*) ;; => 14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defmethod evaluate ((node op-node))
  (apply (value node) 
         (list (evaluate (left-node node))
               (evaluate (right-node node)))))
```

can be written:

```
(defmethod evaluate ((node op-node))
  (funcall (value node) 
           (evaluate (left-node node))
           (evaluate (right-node node))))
```

For this example, instead of different subclasses for every binary operation, you could just use a `binop` class and instantiate it with the respective functions, since they share the same `evaluate` method, but that depends on what else you want do do with the nodes. (Maybe, for example, you want to have different `print-object` methods for each of them.)

(Also, using toplevel `setf`s on unestablished symbols is considered bad style, but I suppose this was just for testing and demonstration purposes. In real code, `defparameter` or `defvar` should be used.)

Comment: Is there any difference between using `apply` and `funcall` in this case? Are there cases where one is better usage instead of the other? The `binop` class hint is very good! I thought of abstracting it more but I wasn't sure how to do it without getting the code too confusing.

Comment: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_funcal.htm: `(funcall function arg1 arg2 ...) == (apply function arg1 arg2 ... nil) ==  (apply function (list arg1 arg2 ...))`. So no, there is no difference in this case. Just use whatever is less convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defmethod evaluate (value-node)
  (value value-node))
```

try calling (evaluate 't). Why did that method get called?